# Set directory where MinKNOW writes FAST5 files

Tags: nanopore, ngs, minion, minknow

I would like to set the folder in which MinKNOW writes the raw data. How can I do this? I do not currently know where MinKNOW will output my data. What is the default directory where MinKNOW outputs the data? My OS is Mac OS X.

Comment: Important to mention your operating system. At least for Linux, there is a user.conf file somewhere in /opt/ONT/ (don't remember the exact path, but find will help you find it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a page explaining where this is set up in a `user_conf` file here:

https://community.nanoporetech.com/support/faq/test1/minknow/minknow/how-do-i-change-the-directory-for-the-reads-folder?search_term=user_conf

Windows

Open Notepad with administrative rights (search for notepad, right click and then select run as administrator). Select open file and navigate to C:\ProgramFiles\OxfordNanopore\MinKNOW\conf and then open user_conf to view the script. Under output_dirs change the two instances of "C:\data" (default read location) to the directory required. Please note the "\" is important.

Mac OS

Go to /Applications/MinKNOW.app/Contents/Resources/conf/user_conf and open user_conf to view the script. Under output_dirs replace the default path "/Library/MinKNOW/data" with your path of choice.

Ubuntu

Go to /opt/ONT/MinKNOW/conf and open user_conf to view the script. Under output_dirs replace the default path "/var/lib/MinKNOW/data/reads" with your path of choice.